# HTTP Request framework for Android that supports non-blocking IO

Tags: android, retrofit, nio, nonblocking, android-networking

I have been looking for a "NON-BLOCKING IO" HTTP Request framework but having hard time finding much. Looked at OkHttp, Retrofit and few others but looks like both of them don't do non-blocking IO (unless I missed something) - they manage a tread pool and send somewhat blocking requests through blocking individual threads.

Looks like android supports non-blocking network IO through something called "nio channels" "https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/package-summary" but don't want to reinvent the wheel and would rather use some existing HTTP framework to send request that raw sockets, if there is one.

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find what you're looking for in [Netty](https://netty.io/index.html) 4.1.
It has official [Android Support](https://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.1.html), and is non-blocking front-to-back.